# Dynamic URL re-writing in nginx

Tags: regex, nginx, url-rewriting

I would like to rewrite url in nginx to serve images from directoy as follows.

URI example:

```
/api/v1/image/small/dirl1/dirl2/dirl3/dirl4/abc.jpg

/api/v1/image/small/dirl1/dirl2/dirl3/abc.jpg

/api/v1/image/small/dirl1/abc.jpg
```

So here URI-Part `/api/v1/image/small/` is static.

Now I have stored images of different sizes on server in a sub-directory and I want to serve it from there, where I need to add directory (configurated in software) before image file name and rename the file.
For example

for `/api/v1/image/small/dirl1/dirl2/dirl3/dirl4/abc.jpg`

images must be served from

`/dirl1/dirl2/dirl3/dirl4/content/small_abc.jpg`

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way is to use the `try_files` directive and capture what you need in the location regex. If you have many mappings of this kind, you should consider using `map` directive to match request $uri and use a common location block.

```
location ~ ^/api/vi/image/small/(.+)/([^.]+)\.jpg$ {
    try_files /$1/content/small_$2.jpg =404;
}
```